# Evaluate string with math operators

Tags: c#, string, parsing, math, evaluation

Is there an easy way to evaluate strings like
`"(4+8)*2"`
So that you'd get the int value of 24?

Or is there a lot of work needed to get this done...?

Comment: You can have a look at: [The expression evaluator revisited (Eval function in 100% managed .NET)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/eval3.aspx)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Ncalc:

```
Expression e = new Expression("(4+8)*2");
Debug.Assert(24 == e.Evaluate());
```

http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Also, this question had been previously asked and has some interesting answers including Ncalc : [Evaluating string "3*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Answer (score 46):

Someone else added this and then it got deleted. I thought it was pretty cool because no 3rd party libraries required.

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Evaluate("(4+8)*2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double Evaluate(string expression)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("expression", typeof(string), expression);
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In my use, this solution was about 1.5x faster than NCalc, while being equally stable (at least for what I was doing).  It handled boolean expressions just as same as NCalc.  This should be advertised more.

Comment: This doesn't handle powers or square roots.

Comment: this solution is perfect for simple expressions as i need it. Thank you for re-posting it.

Comment: Meanwhile i found a problem: numbers with fractions (like 1.5) are parsed with point (.) being the only allowed separator. is this correct? Can i rely on this in every language? in german the standard separator for fractions is komma (,). But when i use this, the parsing fails.

Comment: zreptil: you have to assure that all number values within your expression are written to string with the InvariantCulture --> i.e.: myDouble.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Does anyone have a link to anything that would lay out the limitations of this technique? What is allowed/not allowed, etc.

Comment: Don't support log, power and exponential functions

Comment: Not a bad answer but it's a bit wordy you can just: double.Parse(new ystem.Data.DataTable().Compute(expression, ""))

Comment: Very clever solution. But additional downside is that it doesn't support bitwise operations, such as | for OR, & for AND, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You need a Math Expression Parser for that. Below are resources on that:

- (commercial) http://www.bestcode.com/html/bcparser_net.html
- (open source) http://ncalc.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace#jacenet
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MathieuMathParser.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/matheval.aspx