# Execute Expression Stored in a String

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app of windows phone 8.1. I want to execute an expression at run time that is stored in a string variable. For Example:

```
string exp = "4+5-2";
```

I can do this in desktop application by following code:

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
object result = sc.Eval(expr);
```

But this code is not working there. It causes application to crash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# evaluating string "3\*(4+2)" yield int 18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Comment: No, i need help in a code that can be executed on windows phone app.

Comment: Can't you use the answer in LiamK's comment that Sébastien Ros - MSFT posted?

Comment: Or the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838918/evaluate-c-sharp-string-with-math-operators (if Ncalc can't be used, other questions have found that Jace.NET works well for WP8 apps)

Comment: Ncalc isnt working i have tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use  [Jace.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jace/)(Just Another Calculation Engine) nuget package. It supports WP8.1:

```
 private CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();

 private void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    double result = engine.Calculate(ExpressionTextBox.Text);
    ExpressionTextBox.Text = result.ToString();  // displays the result
 }
```

For more info check this [link](https://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/category/jace-net/) and its repository on [Github](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any the packages suggested in the duplicate questions or comments and really just want to roll your own parser, then the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is as good as any. Take the pseudo-code from Wikipedia and implement it in C#.

As a bonus, you could probably add some logic to go beyond basic arithmetic operations with that algorithm if you really need it (e.g. support invoking a function by name).