# How can I parse math operator from string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've a dropdown like this

```
                    @Html.DropDownList("Operator", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "/", Value = "/", Selected = true},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "*", Value = "*"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "+", Value = "+"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "-", Value = "-"}
                }, new {@Class = "form-control", @Id = "Operator"})
```

In my action method I want to use var1 Operator var2.
Suppose 10 Operator  15 = 25 when Operator = "+"
Is it possible?

Comment: There are no built-in ways (though you can search for "C# evaluate math expression" - it may give you some ideas). If you don't need full-fledged math expression evaluation, then you can just use a simple `switch` (or `map/Dictionary` of `Func<Double, Double, Double>`) to do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate C# string with math operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838918/evaluate-c-sharp-string-with-math-operators)

Answer (score 3):

Recently I was using open-source library for parsing math expressions provided as strings. The parser / evaluator name is mXparser.

http://mxparser.codeplex.com/

http://mathparser.org/

Example:

```
Expression e = new Expression("2+3/(4+1)");
double v = e.calculate();
```

Additionally - this software is using mXparser as well - you can learn the syntax [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro).

Best regards