# C# - Computing Mathematical equation from Strings only

Tags: c#

To make it short what I want to do is convert a simple string like "/" into the actual  /   symbol so I can use it like this.

The button.Text in the code below will be one of these
"+" , "-", "/", "*"

```
Button button = (Button)sender;

lblAns.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtNum1.Text) + button.Text + Convert.ToDouble(txtNum2.Text)).ToString();
```

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Well what's wrong?

Comment: you can't do that.  you need to parse the string, and if you see `/`, you'll know you need to divide.  You can't just convert the string into code (I know, you really can, but you don't want to)

Comment: Oh haha, I was assuming he wanted to display the formula on the label, not the actual mathematical result!  No, this is torturing all good coding principals in many ways.

Comment: haha, yes i know its not the normal way of doing it but i like to find new an unique ways of doing things, if i can get that code to work it will replace 13 other lines of code. So i would prefer to use only 2 instead of 13.

Comment: @iankorkie -- You will learn as you build experience that shorter is not *always* better.  There are tried and true principals to the art of software development, many of which you're breaking by applying your shortcuts.

Comment: @iankorkie check my answer below, you can do it using strings only as you want.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Actually he can check my answer below.

Comment: @iankorkie please edit your post to provide expected result and concrete criteria for acceptable answer. So far you just comment "I don't like you suggestion" - this is not a way to create Q/A pairs on SO. Also make sure to clarify how it is different from usual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838918/evaluate-c-sharp-string-with-math-operators

Comment: Thanks all for the advice, I will take it all in account in the future ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can actually do that this way:

**Compute a Mathematical Operation using Strings Only in C#**

```
string statement = txtNum1.Text + button.Text + txtNum2.Text;
lblAns.Text = new System.Data.DataTable().Compute(statement, "").ToString();
```

Working [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0bfvc9).

```
string result = (new System.Data.DataTable()).Compute("5 * 4 + 1", "").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints 21
```

Comment: @iankorkie check the first two lines. What is below is another method.

Comment: Awsome it works, thanks allot