# Evaluate (sum) multiple string delimited in csharp?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

How i can evaluate this string  with this delimiter #c"stringtosum"#g

code1,code2,**#c55+35+97#g**,coden,code3,code4,**#c44+25+07#g**coden

55+35+97=187

44+25+07=76

and output this

code1,code2,**#c187#g**,coden,code3,code4,**#c76#g**coden

i am using this two string ,**#c55+35+97#g** ,**#c44+25+07#g** ,, im tring to evaluate (sum)  this two

55+35+97=187

44+25+07=76

and output this

code1,code2,#c**187**#g,coden,code3,code4,#c**76**#gcoden

i have multiple string to sum

Comment: can you be a little bit clear on what you trying do, also the strings you are using

Comment: i am using this two string ,#c55+35+97#g  ,#c44+25+07#g                             ,, im tring to evaluate (sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use a regular expression like `#c([^#]*)#` to find the matches.  Then you just need to take the string in the grouping, split on the plus sign, parse the values to integers, and do the sum, like this.

```
string input = "code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#gcoden";

string output = Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    "#c([^#]*)#", 
    m => "#c" + m.Groups[1].Value.Split('+').Sum(int.Parse) + "#");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Outputs

> code1,code2,#c187#g,coden,code3,code4,#c76#gcoden

Answer (score 1):

> please help me

well...since you asked nicely.

```
 var str = "code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#g,coden";
        var parts = str.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            var temp = parts[i];

            if (temp.StartsWith("#c") && temp.EndsWith("#g"))
            {
                var nums = temp.Substring(2, temp.Length - 4).Split(new[] { "+" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                temp = $"#c{nums.Sum(int.Parse)}#g";
            }
            builder.Append(temp);
            if (i != parts.Length-1)
                builder.Append(",");
        }

        var output = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I would go with @juharr answer.  It is cleaner, and I think i altered your initial string at the end there.  Wasn't sure if it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions to identify the sections of the string that you would like to parse and evaluate and then you can bring in the [Jace.NET NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jace) to evaluate the calculations. This method would work for all types of arithmetic operations instead of only summations:

```
var inputString = "code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#gcoden";
var calcEngine = new CalculationEngine();       // add "using Jace;" at the top of your code file to bring in the CalculationEngine
var outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, "#c([^#]*)#g", m => "#c" + calcEngine.Calculate(m.Groups[1].Value).ToString() + "#g");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking into regular expressions (regex). Regex allows you to parse through a string and pick out certain parts. From there, you can add them and then substitute them back into your string.

As an example, "\d*+\d*" will allow you to select the two substrings "55+35+97" and "44+25+07"

Comment: i want sum the string i dont know how i can do this

Comment: i cant sum in regex

Comment: i dont know How could I sum in regex

Comment: i have multiple string to sum

Comment: You can assign say "55+39+97" to its own string variable. There are several answers to execute string equations as math : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838918/evaluate-c-sharp-string-with-math-operators?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: but in my text exist multiple string how i could evaluate all strings

Comment: Iterate through each of the matches that the regex returns. foreach match, assign to string, compute the sum, replace in your string, then iterate to the next match.