# Evaluating List<String> as a mathematical expression

Tags: c#, expression-evaluation

I have a `List<String>` that is full of values and operators.

```
["123", "+", "(", "890", "-", "15.00", ")"]
```

I know that I can make an algorithm that will push these numbers and and operators onto a stack and pop them off and evaluate as I go.  But, is there a better way to do with without using a external library?

Comment: Are these broken up from user input or fed to you by some other system?

Comment: Are you trying to do it without either using an existing library OR writing your own implementation? Or are you looking for a library included in the standard libraries?

Comment: I am looking for something that is included in the standard library or I will write my own algorithm.

Comment: Use can use any implementation of the standard infix (inorder) expression evaluator... [Sample Code to Evaluate an Infix Expression](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm)

Comment: I have been very happy with ILCalc (http://ilcalc.codeplex.com/). It is an external library, but it is on codeplex, so you get source code if you need to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pushing the numbers and operators onto a stack would be an interpreter.

The obvious better way to do this (for some definition of "better") is to **write a compiler!**

You already have the input split into lexical tokens, so you can skip implementing a lexer and can dive right into building the AST. You can find suitable classes to transform your input to in the [System.​Linq.​Expressions Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx); have a look at the [Expression Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx). You can wrap the result in a lambda expression, compile it to IL and execute it on the CLR!

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to use a compiler to evaluate a constant, but if he had variables then it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the `List` and then let the compiler evaluate it at runtime as Mehrdad stated.

```
Expression e = new Expression("5 * 2"); 
e.Evaluate();
```

I found a very similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

update :

[NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) "NCalc - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET" even though this is an external library I think it is an open source project which means you can add the code directly to your project.

Update :

You can use the `String.Join` function to join the List.

```
string formula = String.Join("",listMathOperators);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Expression class you're using in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the C# compiler classes in the .NET framework to evaluate it as a C# expression...

Comment: Do you have a link or example of this?

Comment: You'd need to validate the strings first, otherwise you could be executing a lot more than you expect.

Comment: Do you mean CodeDOM or Expression trees?

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete class that calculates any expression.

First, you need to extract all strings of your list to a single string, like:

```
string sExpression = "123+(890-15.00)";
```

Second, you need to evaluate this expression in a parser, I have a complete class that makes this for you, but I can't attach files here.