# Converting a String value with operator signs in C#

Tags: c#, variables

```
 string stringValue = "1+2+3";
```

How can I convert the above string value with **operators**, "1+2+3", so that it can be assigned to the intvalue as shown below in C#.

```
 int intValue = 1+2+3;
```

i.e  intValue = 6;

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Comment: You could compile it with `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` of course...

Comment: Lol that's actually the answer there. My god, what happened to good old stack based processing of a simple mathematical expression?

Comment: What mathematical operators might the string contain?

Comment: Please try harder to research instead of asking these redundant questions. It's easier to google than to type all those stuff you've typed.

Comment: Define "operators"? Do you want to work with just base 10 integers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile on the fly. See for example [Evaluate C# Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function) or [Flee](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19768/Flee-Fast-Lightweight-Expression-Evaluator).

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable.Compute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)

```
  var result = new DataTable().Compute("2-3/4*12", null);
```

ANd this has been asked so many times before.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library in many projects: [C# calculation engine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246374/A-Calculation-Engine-for-NET)

It's very simple to use:

```
var ce = new CalcEngine();
double result = (double)ce.Evaluate("1+2+3");
```