# C# - Operator Return type

Tags: c#, .net

I need to make some math operations like : a+b , a-b, a/b, a*b and so on.

I want to know if there exists Operator return type, so when I call the method (that returns the operator) to use that returned data (so the operator).

If doesn't exist how can I get that operator from a string. For instance:

```
string myOperator = "+";
int a = 5, b = 10;
int outcome = 0;
```

I need to make :

```
outcome = a + b;
```

So I need that + operator. What should I use as return type if I make a method that gives me somehow that operator?

Comment: why dont you return the myOperator value - that already has operator !

Comment: Can you give some more example code of what you want to do? It's not really clear from your description unfortunately.

Comment: just write `int outcome = a + b;`... Or are you trying to do this with your own type instead of `int`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# evaluating string "3\*(4+2)" yield int 18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing operator return type in C#. You need to parse the operator manually in C#. See this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/patricklundin/MathExpParser12062005062213AM/MathExpParser.aspx or create your own parser.

```
 int a = 3, b = 7;
 Operator(a, b, "+"); // 10

int Operator (int op1, int op2, string op)
{
    if (op == "+") return op1 + op2;
    if (op == "-") return op1 - op2;
    if (op == "*") return op1 * op2;
    if (op == "/") return op1 / op2;

    throw new ArgumentException("Specify a valid operator", "op");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no return type for an operator. However, you can use `Func<T1,T2,R>` to make a functor that has the behavior of the operator, but has the syntax of a function.

```
Func<int,int,int> myOperator1 = (x,y) => (x+y);
Func<int,int,int> myOperator2 = (x,y) => (x-y);
int a = 5, b = 10;
int outcome1 = myOperator1(a, b); // Returns 15
int outcome2 = myOperator2(a, b); // Returns -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question.. how do I parse my intended operator, expressed as a string?

Grossly oversimplified... but maybe something like this?

```
int fuzzyMath(int a, int b, string literalOperator) {
     string cleanedOperator = literalOperator.Trim();
     if ("+".Equals(cleanedOperator )) {
          return a+b;
     } else if ("-".Equals(cleanedOperator )) {
          return a-b;
     } //and so on
}
```

Im not sure you can derive an operator as a type, or value that can freely be used in an expression, but you can test for expected literal values and compute based on that...