# any easier way to parse and solve expression in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to evaluate expressions that are inputted as strings

example: `string svar1="1 * 2 * 3";`

I need to be able to evaluate that to answer 6.

I am thinking about parsing it by spaces, then match the operators with switch to each functions (need to do +,-,*,/,%, etc) but it seems like a very tedious way as there are so many operators to code. Is there a way to convert a char/string containing an operator into actual operator?

Comment: How about brackets "()" or powersigns "^" ?

Comment: If it is not a homewok you can use NCalc, otherwise, you will follow the path of all students..

Answer (score 4):

one easy way is to use [DataTable.Compute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        var result = table.Compute("1 * 2 * 3","");
    }
```

Comment: An interesting, if not completely abusive and hacked, approach. This may not work for more *complex* expressions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I don't know the limit of it but you always need to test to make sure you get want you want :-)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Abusive in the sense of using an elephant gun to kill a flea.  Not hacked at all -- parsing and evaluating mathematical expressions is a core requirement of the `Compute` method.  There's just additional ability for those expressions to include field accesses which won't be used here.

Comment: How does this satisfy the documented requirement that "the expression parameter requires an aggregate function" ?

Comment: @BenVoigt 1 and 2 and 3 are actually 3 aggregated values

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality is not included in any standard .NET assembly. Your method, in addition to being tedious, is going to be error prone.

You are looking for a math expression parser, [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is one such library.

Comment: System.Data.DataTable does have it

Comment: @Fredou In a very hacked/abusive way, yes. Given that it was intended for *database* expressions, using it in place of a math parser probably isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a library called NCalc can accomplish what you need.

[Evaluating string "3*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Answer (score 0):

If you want some insight/code to demonstrate how this is done properly, using correct rules of precedence, in C# this is a good sequence of articles:

http://ericwhite.com/blog/map/recursive-descent-parser/