# How can you cut a string into 3 parts?

Tags: c#

I have a TextBox where a user can enter a calculation, such as `100+200` on his keyboard.

How can I break the string into three parts, like:

```
string mySum = "200+800"; //Just and example of what he may enter into the textbox
int Operator = mySum.IndexOf('+');
string TheOperator = "+";
string part1 = (mySum.Substring(1, Operator - 1));
mySum.Remove(int.Parse(part1), Operator);
string part2 = (mySum);

//Calculate

int Answer = int.Parse(part1) + TheOperator + int.Parse(part2);
Messagebox.Show(Asnwer.toString()); //Message box should display 1000
```

Firstly I know this is wrong, but I am highly unsure how to do this. Ive looked everywhere but I can't find anything related directly to this

Comment: Do you want to do some calculation with string?

Comment: use Split method. var numbers =  mySum.Split('+');

Comment: @Mr.香港人 I know it sounds ridiculous... xD

Comment: Do you really need to use "Split" function? or you can use any method to do the calculation?

Comment: A similiar question which discusses the generic options available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `string.Split` as follows:

```
// ...

var parts = mySum.Split('+');
var part1 = parts[0]; // 200
var operatorString = parts[1]; // +
var part2 = parts[2]; // 800

// ...
```

Comment: This will actually produce the following - part1 = "2", operatorString = "0" part2 = "0". I can see you probably meant to use parts[0], parts[1] and parts[2] instead, but the split character is also not included in the output, so parts would only have 2 elements, not 3.

Comment: @Aidan - i think i am fastest as per SO timing ...any ways....at lest you accepted answer....:)

Comment: @PranayRana Haha, I'm sorry. Im still very new with C# syntax, Ian Chu's answer looks the most simple and did what I wanted it to do. Although thanks for answering :) edit: If I had enough reputation, I would have upvoted your answer as well <3

Comment: Fastest answer doesn't always mean the best answer :)

Answer (score 2):

simple as this , make use of Split function

split by char

```
string[] words = s.Split('+', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Split by char array , when there is more than one char

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '+', '*' };
    string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters,
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

you can also make use of regular expression like this

```
string value = "cat\r\ndog\r\nanimal\r\nperson";
    // Split the string on line breaks.
    // ... The return value from Split is a string array 
   string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do some simple calculation, try this

From [Evaluating string "3*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18):

```
using System.Data;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var v = dt.Compute("200+800","");
```

Answer (score 1):

split would work here.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string mySum = "200+800";
        int totalSum = 0;
        foreach(var op in mySum.Split('+'))
        {
            totalSum += Convert.ToInt16(op);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(totalSum);
    }
}
```

[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GxS62Z) is fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only calculate you can do like this:

```
 var result = new System.Data.DataTable().Compute("200+800", null);
 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Hope helps