# Go through a string and check if contains a char and save the chars before in a list

Tags: c#, string, split

I want go through a string, and check if in the string is a char available.
For example:
My string is: `string test = "100+20+3-17+2"`
So now I go through my string and check the chars:

```
List<string> numbers= new List<string>();
foreach( char c in test)
{
   if (c =='+'|| c =='-'||c =='/'||c =='*')
   {
     //Now here i want to save all chars before '+' '-'  '/'  '*' in my list numbers. in this example: save 100, 20,3,17,2 in my list
   }
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: _"here i want to save all chars"_ what means _save_? Is it important to save the pairs which belong to specific characters like in `100+20` or doesn't it matter if you don't know later to which character they belonged, like in `100+20/30`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter No i want know later which character will be entered.
But i want further than total the whole numbers..
I think that will be very difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just split your string with the characters

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
string test = "100+20+3-17+2";
char[] chars = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
numbers = test.Split(chars).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello fubo,
nice that solution works fine.
But now if i want total the numbers, how can i work furhter with the numbers?

Comment: @saaami11 are you expecting 108?

Comment: Yes Sarvesh im expecting 108

Comment: @saaami11 thats a completely different question. you need to remember the arithmetic operators. and what about multiplication and division first, then addition and subtraction?

Comment: Hmm yeah thats my problem., it want be so easy to make that hm?

Comment: no not so easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). As you go through the original string to check chars add them to the StringBuilder. When you find a splitter char add StringBuilder.ToString in the list and empty the StringBuilder.

The code should look something like the following (haven't tested it):

```
List<string> numbers= new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach( char c in test)
{
    if (c =='+'|| c =='-'||c =='/'||c =='*')
    {
        //Now here i want to save all chars before '+' '-'  '/'  '*' in my list numbers. in this example: save 100, 20,3,17,2 in my list

        numbers.Add(sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If char not in '+', '-', '/', '*', you can concat the chars in string. When operator comes you can add the sting to list, and empty string

```
List<string> numbers= new List<string>();
string curNumber="";
foreach( char c in test)
{
   if (c =='+'|| c =='-'||c =='/'||c =='*')
   {
     numbers.Add(curNumber);
     curNumber="";
   }
   else
   {
     //also you can add operators in other list here
     curNumber+=c.ToString();
   }
}
numbers.Add(curNumber);
```

Comment: Like i ask above,  but now if i want total the numbers, how can i work furhter with the numbers? 
The result in this example is 108?

Answer (score 0):

use [`String.Split(Char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an array of the splitted string

Comment: "this" isn't very descriptive, you should include the relevant information from that link in your answer. If the link were to die, then so would your answer