# how to convert a formula stored in a string to double?

Tags: c#

I have a string with values stored as:

```
string formula = "(10.5+10.5)/(2*5)";
```

`double a=convert.ToDouble((10.5+10.5)/(2*5))` is working fine but i need to solve it like double `a=convert.ToDouble(formula)`. Is it possible? I'm geeting error input string is not in correct format.

Comment: This SO question has already answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply pass a formula to `Convert.ToDouble` and expect that it will calculate it. You need to **compute** the formula.

The good way is to implement a parser, which will build an expression tree, and calcultate the value.

Another hacky solution is to utilize `Compute` method of `DataTable`:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
decimal result = (decimal)table.Compute(formula);
```

Note that it returns `decimal` object. You can now use `Convert` to make it `double`, if you need:

```
double resultDouble = Convert.ToDouble(result);
```