# How do i target a certain part of a string C#

Tags: c#

I've literally just started looking at c# like an hour ago and i thought i would try and make a calculator i have one problem and this is the only problem.

I have a way of getting the value of the first value being entered but have no other way to figure out the second value without it showing the entire string being entered.

```
private void buttonEQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string valueTWO;
   valueTWO = textBox1.Text;
   Console.WriteLine(valueTWO);

}
```

So whatever the person enters it will just log it out say 100-50 for example how do i programmatically tell the program to 'get everything after the -' if possible which im sure it is.

Comment: I would recommend you go through a C# tutorial, otherwise you will have a ton of questions like these and these types of questions are not good questions for StackOverflow. For your specific question, google 'C# substring'.

Comment: i'll have a look at it, i just didn't know what it was called. Thanks

Comment: Or Google for regular expressions. Do you know other languages? How would you parse the inserted expression? If you don't know what to do, you have a different problem than how to do it.

Comment: Ye i do know how to. I know abit in javascript thats where i picked up all the basics

Comment: The String method Split or the Regex method Split is probably what you want. If you are familiar with python Split is similar to split in python. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note that question as asked has more or less nothing to do with actual stated goal (calculator) which is covered in many questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18 or intro chapters to expression parsing (if one wants to do it by hand).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void buttonEQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string valueTWO;
        valueTWO = textBox1.Text;
        string[] s = valueTWO.Split('-');
        // value before "-"
        Console.WriteLine(s[0]);
        // value after "-"
        Console.WriteLine(s[1]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string n = s.Split('-').FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: He doesn't want the first one. He wants the one after the "-".

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `split`-Method:

```
string[] textBoxSplitted = textBox1.Text.Split('-');

string valueTwo = textBoxSplitted[1]; //Second result (the one after the dash)
```

Be aware of that this may fail if the user did not follow the format 'XXX-YYY', so you may check if `textBoxSplitted.Length == 2`.