# C#: Convert user input string "Pi" to double Math.PI

Tags: c#, converters

e.g.

Converting between radians and degrees, 7 Pi radians = 1260 degrees

User input for radians.

Trying to convert a user input string "Pi" to Math.Pi, to calculate.

Comment: Can you post the relevant sample of code? If I understand correctly, you could set a constant to pi using `const decimal pi = 3.14159;` or `var pi = Math.Pi;`

Comment: So the user is actually inputting "0.5 Pi" if he wants 90°?

Comment: Sounds like you're after an [equation evaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18).  It's doable, but I'd recommend picking one of the libraries that do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the input you allow the user.

If it's just something like `0.5 Pi` or `3 Pi` and you want the actual value for it, you can simply remove the `Pi` part from the input string, parse the remaining string into a number and multiply it with `Math.PI`

```
Regex pi = new Regex(@"\s*pi\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var v = pi.Replace(input, "");
double d = Convert.ToDouble(v);
double rad = d * Math.Pi;
```

If you have more complex inputs like `3/4 Pi` or even more complex formulas, you'll need some sort of formula-interpreter. Many of them would be able to deal with constants like Pi.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Looks like you need to strip the string out and then use a formula.

Something like:

```
const string pi = "pi";
var input = "7pi";
var containsPi = (input.IndexOf(pi) > -1)
var inputDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(input.Replace(input, pi, ""));
if (containsPi ) inputDecimal = inputDecimal * Math.Pi;
var resultInDegreees = inputDecimal * 180.0 / Math.Pi;
```