# c# if function: get operator from Text file

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is it possible to write an if statement with a changing operator?

The operator (<,>, =<; >=, =) has been saved earlier in a text file and is now a available in a string array called Parameter.

For example: Parameter [0] = {"<"};

The code should look like:

```
if (3 "Parameter[0]" 5) {//do something}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating string "3\*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>> functions = ...;
functions.Add("<", (a,b) => a < b);
functions.Add(">", (a,b) => a > b);
```

Then to use it:

```
if(functions[Parameter[0]](3, 5)){...}
```

Comment: Yeah it wasn't exactly correct, I've fixed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness to the other two answers, you can return a custom comparer function:

```
public Func<int, int, bool> CustomComparer(string parameter) {
    switch(parameter) {
        case(">="): return (a, b) => a >= b;
        case(">"): return (a, b) => a > b;
        //...
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
if(CustomComparer("<=")(3, 5)) { ... }
```

or:

```
var FirstIsGreater = CustomComparer(">");
if(FirstIsGreater(3, 5)) {... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If really this is all you need. you can make a switch case:

```
switch(Operator){
  case '<': return a < b;
  case '>': return a > b;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called metaprogramming and is generally not available in C#. In general you would not be able to do this in any staticly-typed language (in the statically typed language that support metaprogramming, the "code string" must be known during compile time). What you can do is:

1. Do as Joel said and just make a switch-case (though this can get ugly if extracting the operator's difficult).
2. Create a dictionary that maps operators to functions, and create a function that extracts the operator from the source string (like lancew did).
3. [Programmatically write runnable C# code and compile it at runtime](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/) (for the love of god, don't actually do this just to compare two numbers).