# How to evalute a math expression given in string form in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm fairly new to programming and c#. I have a problem with a simple calculator program I'm trying to write in visual studio c#. I want to convert my text with numbers and math operators into a number. All my attempts so far have led to no success.
I have tried:

- Double.Parse()
- Convert.Int32()
- Convert.Double()

Here are some images of my code:
[Pic One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KfAx.png)
[Pic Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Liez.png)

Any help would be much appreciated, if there is any extra information you need I would be happy to provide it.

-Retro_Goat

Answer (score -1):

For Pic 1
C# can not take an equation string and convert it to a result, it can take values in an equation form and convert it to a result, i.e.

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32((7 + 3) * 3.5);
```

If you have an equation string you will need to cycle through the string an separate the values and the operations and process them as values or use a processing object, see [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

For Pic 2

```
        double val = 0;
        if(double.TryParse(lblDisplay.Text, out val))
        {
            // val is set to the string value
        }
        else 
        {
           // The string was not a valid number
        }
```

Comment: You can evaluate strings as expressions in c#

Comment: int val = Convert.ToInt32("7 + 3"); is not valid in C#, which is what I was trying to impart

Comment: No, not like that. Like in the link I proposed as a duplicate.